# Angular 5: Read HTML from other components

Tags: angular5

I have 4 Angular components. I would like to read the content of entire component for 3 of them into the 4 component as HTML string.
I would like to use this HTML string to create a WORD document.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to parse html:
http://inikulin.github.io/parse5/

And this to write document: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen